# Necesito crear un upload.php desde php utilizando fopen

Tags: php, fopen

Hola gente llevo toda la noche intentando hacer funcionar el siguiente script, pero  no importa si pongo comillas simples o dobles, siempre me resulta en un error500, la idea es ejecutar el archivo crear.php y que el mismo me cree upload.php
Les dejo el codigo, espero me iluminen.
Pongo asi, por que el foro no me deja pegar mi codigo.

```
$archivo = fopen("uploader.php", "w") or die("error creando fichero!");
$txt = "<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $directorio = "";
    $maxfile = '2000000';

    $nombref = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $userfile_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        $abod = $directorio.$nombref;
        @move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $abod);

echo"<center><b>Done ==> $nombref</b></center>";
}
}
else{
echo'
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="image"><input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></form>';
}
?>
";
fwrite($archivo, $txt);
fclose($archivo);
?>
```

Comment: Si la variable $txt usa comillas dobles para delimitar su contenido, no puedes volver a utilizarlas dentro. Donde las tengas dobles, usa simples y se resolverá. Saludos

Comment: ¿Tratas de escribir fragmentos de código PHP en un archivo de texto? Espero que tengas una buena justificación para hacer eso. Si la tienes bien, entonces,  dentro de `$txt` haz dos cosas: 1. Cambia todas las comillas simples por dobles: 2. PEEEERO, todas esas comillas dobles debes escaparlas con \, por ejemplo: `$txt = "<?php
if(isset($_POST[Submit])){
    $directorio = \"\";
    $maxfile = \"2000000\";  echo\"<center><b>Done ==> $nombref</b></center>\" "` En los arrays, para este caso, puedes omitir las comillas, poniendo solamente la clave, como hice en `$_POST[Submit]`

Comment: bien @A.Cedano realize lo que comentaste el array lo deje sin comillas, y crea el archivo nuevo, el problema ahora es que ese nuevo archivo, esta incompleto.

me quedaria asi

Comment: <?php
if(isset()){
     = "";
     = "2000000";

     = [name];
     = [tmp_name];
    if (isset([name])) {
         = .;
        @move_uploaded_file(, );

echo "<center><b>Done ==> </b></center>";
}
}
else{
echo "
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="image"><input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></form>";
}
?>

Comment: el codigo dentro de $txt es asi

"<?php
if(isset($_POST[Submit])){
    $directorio = \"\";
    $maxfile = \"2000000\";

    $nombref = $_FILES[image][name];
    $userfile_tmp = $_FILES[image][tmp_name];
    if (isset($_FILES[image][name])) {
        $abod = $directorio.$nombref;
        @move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $abod);

echo \"<center><b>Done ==> $nombref</b></center>\";
}
}
else{
echo \"
<form method=\"POST\" action=\"\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"><input type=\"file\" name=\"image\"><input type=\"Submit\" name=\"Submit\" value=\"Submit\"></form>\";
}
?>

Comment: habia utilizado simples en un principio @DavidJP pero me provocaba error 500 y el script no hacia nada, ahora con lo de a. cedano no da error, crea el nuevo archivo, pero inclompleto

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, el problema es que estaba utilizando comillas dobles para $txt la solucion era utilizar una simple de la siguiente forma $txt 'codigo'